# Passing VBA integer array to c# DLL int array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dll, integer

I've made some C# DLLs with multiple public variables in: strings, doubles, arrays of doubles, etc, none of which bother to use getters/setters. I can happily set any of them or read them from VBA by just using:

```
DllThing.variable = VBAVariable
```

This works if the variable is an either a straight variable or array of double and the VBAVariable matches type. However, if my VBAVariable is an array of Integer() and my DllThing.variable is an array of int[] it doesn't work and I get a Run-time error '5', Invalid procedure or call.

I made a test int variable in the same DLL and I can set and retrieve that fine, but it just seems to be VBA Integer() arrays -> C# int[] arrays I can't send (as mentioned double arrays seem to work fine).

Any ideas?

Comment: use Long in VBA, NOT Integer. VBA Integer is: 2 bytes -32,768 to 32,767. Use Long which is the 32 bit equivalent of Int32  in C#

Comment: I thought I tried that, but it works, so I obviously hadn't! >_< Thanks! :)

Comment: No worries - it is a bit strange that they ever had that difference..